# Content inside div went improper after zoom in/out the browser

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div tags inside a div tag, all I want in same line. That I did using some css, but when I zoom out/in browser content goes in different lines.
css code:

```
#about{
    float:left; 
    width:33%;
}
.about-panel{
    width:100%;
}
```

html code:

```
<div class="about-panel">
  <div id="about">
   <p><img style="width:400px;height:280px;margin-top:0%;" src="/media/Banner.png"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="about">
    <p style="margin-left:12%;"><img style="height:280px" src="/media/roto.gif"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="about">
<iframe width="400" height="280" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/o3vMWRWPYzE" `frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`
  </div>
</div>
```

I want all content as it is in same line even after zoom in/out

[image]

How I need the contents to be aligned

[image]

Comment: JSFiddle link would be nice.

Comment: hi Ali, here both pictures and video are under a div, all 3 are inline but when I press ctrl+- they goes something like shows in pictures

Comment: What is wrong in that picture, that's what I want to know?

Comment: I need to play with your code, JSFiddle link would be nice.

Comment: Why do you have three elements with the same `id`?

Comment: so that I can apply same properties to all three elements...by the way here is JSfidle link:http://jsfiddle.net/hmHyQ/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jsfiddle would have been nice but for time being,   try `display:inline-block;` in you `about-panel`. It throwing up because of missing `display` type for the `div` most probably!!

```
.about-panel{
   width:100%;
   display:inline-block; /* add this and check*/
 }
 #about{
   float:left; 
   width:33%;
 }
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hmHyQ/11/, but here content is coming inline still you can take a look of code....

Comment: i didn't get you...you problem was that the content is breaking out of line..right??? and now even on zoom they would be in the line...or m i missing something?

Comment: now I got the upto 80% satisfactory fix, thanks man,,,,I will approve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one id.. change the "about" to class.. That should work!